# ASP.net: How to toggle a checkbox based on a dropdownlist selection

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, checkbox, toggle

I have a dropdownlist control and it's populated with a list of peoples names from a database. I want to enable a CheckBox control if the user selects a person in the list and disable the checkbox if they select BLANK (also an option in the list).

Here is a portion of my code...

```
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblAssignedTo1" runat="server" Text="Assigned To:"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAssignedTo1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="dsAssignedTo" DataTextField="StaffName" DataValueField="StaffID"><asp:ListItem Text="" /></asp:DropDownList></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="LabelEmail1" runat="server" Text="Send Email:"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox ID="cbEmail1" runat="server" Checked="true" /></td>
    </tr>
```

The checkbox is a trigger to send an email to the person selected from the list. I want it to default the checkbox to "enabled" if a person is selected from the list to make sure the program I am using is going to send an email later on.

I had a look at http://api.jquery.com/change/ for an example of this, but it's not using a checkbox control, so not sure if it would work. Sorry I am new to jScript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure HTML and JavaScript approach would look something like this:

```
<select id="people">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="person1">Person 1</option>
    <option value="person2">Person 2</option>
    <option value="person3">Person 3</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" name="sendemail" id="sendemail" disabled="disabled" />
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#people').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $('#sendemail').attr('disabled', 'disabled');   
        }
        else {
            $('#sendemail').removeAttr('disabled');   
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AEXpG/

In terms of your code, just grab the select list and checkbox ClientId and then apply the above jQuery code to them.

Comment: @Fernando68 Please accept the answer if it did the trick for you.

Comment: How? Sorry I am new here. I do not see an "ACCEPT" button or link.